# Socket.io how to send JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

How to send JavaScript Object with `Socket.io` from server to client? I'm using Socket.io as WebSocket(sending with `.send()` and listen with `message` event).
When I'm trying to do something like on server-side:

```
var myObject = {
    message: 'Hello World!'
}

socket.send(myObject);
```

on client-side I'm getting only this String: `[object Object]`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You actually need to emit an event instead:

```
 socket.emit('yourEvent', myObject);
```

If you use `.send()`, you are simply sending the string representation of your object, which is where the problem is occurring.  Note that you can use `.send()`, but you would have to JSON-encode the object first, and decode it on reception.

Unless you have a specific reason, it's best to use the standard Socket.IO `.emit()` method, as it does all of this for you.  That's what it is there for.

Comment: Thank you. but how to pars JSON in server side and use it?

Comment: Thank you again . I have read most of them. But they use the String variable.

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into this issue using some older example. Here is the answer I found: [Migrating 0.6 to 0.7+](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7+#sending-data-to-client), which I reproduce below.

---

In v0.6, `socket.send` would automatically convert an object like `{a: 'b'}` to JSON. You would send data to a client with:

```
socket.send({a: 'b'});
```

While this is cool, it poses a fundamental problem. JSON not only encodes objects, but also strings, numbers, etc! So, the API is more clear if you explicitly state you want to pass JSON (since there's a performance penalty associated with encoding/decoding JSON).

In v0.7, use the `json` flag:

```
socket.json.send({a: 'b'});
```

Now you can also emit and receive custom events between the browser and server:

```
socket.emit('my_event', {a: 'b'});
```

Arguments for events get encoded in JSON automatically for you.

Answer (score 9):

`socket.send()` doesn't understand object but it enjoys with JSON. You can use this way:

```
socket.send(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

And use `JSON.parse(json)` to parse JSON to Object.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this on your server-side

`socket.json.send({ your : 'data' });`

and the `JSON.parse()` method on your client-side.

Comment: Works like a charm for me when sending to my Android-client, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

In socket.io V4.x, there is no need to use `JSON.stringify()`:

> There is no need to run JSON.stringify() on objects as it will be done for you.

e.g.

```
// BAD
socket.emit("hello", JSON.stringify({ name: "John" }));

// GOOD
socket.emit("hello", { name: "John" });
```

more info on this [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/#Basic-emit).