# Web Sockets Objects not having assigned functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am using javascript (p5.js) and node.js w/ express and socket.io.

This is a portion of my current code that I think the problem lies in:

```js
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j ++){
      for (var k = 0; k < 3; k ++){
        for (var l = 0; l < 3; l ++){
          socket.emit('grid', grid[i][j][k][l]);
        }
      }
    } 
  }
  socket.on('grid', test);
}
function test(gridElement){
  gridElement.show();
  console.log('showing');
}
```

The idea is that there is a 4 dimensional 'grid', and each element in the grid is a CELL. Each cell has the following properties associated to it:

```
function Cell(x, y, w, val){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.w = w;
this.revealed = true;
this.val = round(val);
```

}

```
Cell.prototype.show = function(){
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.w);
    text(this.val, this.x + this.w/2, this.y + this.w/2);
  }
```

As it says, each cell has a 'show' function to display the cell. This usually works.

The problem is, after I emit the element back from the server, and try to run:

```
gridElement.show();
```

I get an error saying 'gridElement.show is not a function'

Any ideas on what's wrong and how to fix it? I have the server code if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket.io how to send JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805130/socket-io-how-to-send-javascript-object)

Comment: My guess is that. `emit()` uses `JSON.stringify` under the hood, so any functions which you have in the cell instance won't be preserved once it is parsed back. Maybe consider making a `.fromData()` method on your Cell class

Comment: @BENARDPatrick I don't think so, since I was already using socket.broadcast.emit() in my server code...

Comment: @NickParsons I'm not familiar with .fromData() at all, could you elaborate a bit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the cell data between client and server, but when it arrives at the other end, it will be a plain object not a Cell object.  socket.io uses JSON as the data transfer format and JSON does not preserve the type of object it is, only the data of the object.

You will have to write code to turn it into a Cell object with your methods on it.  Typically, one would do that by creating a constructor for your object that accepts a plain object as an argument and it grabs the data out of that plain object and then when you receive that data from the other end, you create a new Cell object and pass it the data you just received:

```
function Cell(data) {
    this.x = data.x;
    this.y = data.y;
    this.w = data.w;
    this.val = data.val;
}

socket.on('grid', function(data) {
    // data here is a plain object
    let gridElement = new Cell(data);
    gridElement.show();        
});
```

Or, using the constructor your question already shows:

```
socket.on('grid', function(data) {
    // data here is a plain object
    let gridElement = new Cell(data.x, data.y, data.h, data.val);
    gridElement.show();        
});
```

Comment: would this require having two Cell constructors? One for the server and one for the client which you have to maintain in two places?

Comment: @NickParsons - It requires having the Cell code on both client and sever, but you can share one implementation with appropriate module and code layout.

Comment: @jfriend00   If you look at my original post, I have changed my 'test' function for your function(data)... I tested it out, and I no longer have the error BUT I still don't see the cell? I haven't edited the server code yet, am I meant to change something there?

Comment: @user769321 - we would have to see more of the implementation to know what else might be missing.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you mind if I edit my question and add screenshots of the different server, sketch and cell files?

Comment: I have tried console.logging my cells just before I call the 'show' function. It does look like all changes I made in the server have been made... it's just not _showing_ them

Comment: @user769321 - I think we've answered your original question for this next part of the problem. Perhaps it would be better to write a new question. And do not ever post code as screenshots. Always post it as text so people can copy it into answers and it can be searched.

Comment: Sure thing. I will try some more tests and try to narrow down where the problem is, and then I'll post another question if needed. Thanks

Comment: @jfriend00 I am still having some problems, and have made a more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938067/socket-io-websockets-cannot-emit-and-show-an-object  Any help would be much appreciated